# Count click over image and save

Tags: javascript, arrays, save

I have a photo sharing program Webpage program "www.look-up-photos.com", (HTML and Javascript) and I would like to know the number of times an image is opened.
The program is based on an array

```
var mainArray = [
[
    "JS_00469-40.jpg",
    null,
    "Angola, Cuando Cubango, Menongue",
    "Tar road",
    "SONY, FE 24-105mm F4 G OSS",
    4,
    "2023/08/11",
    "2.8 MB 5366x3577"
  ],
  [
    "JS_00473-7.jpg",
    null,
    "Angola, Huambo",
    "Queve river, Cuvo river",
    "SONY, FE 24-105mm F4 G OSS",
    3,
    "2023/08/12",
    "3.5 MB 6000x4000"
  ],
  [
    "JS_00475-8.jpg",
    null,
    "Angola, Huambo",
    "Tar road",
    "SONY, FE 24-105mm F4 G OSS",
    0,
    "2023/08/12",
    "3.3 MB 5405x3216"
  ],
  [
    "P1001317-1.jpg",
    null,
    "Angola, Alto Hama",
    "Águas frias, Quinta do Pereira, turkey",
    "OM Digital Solutions, OLYMPUS M.40-150mm F2.8",
    5,
    "2023/08/12",
    "3.9 MB 3888x5184"
  ],....]
```

with the Name, Address, Number of clicks and other attributes of each photo.
What I want is to count the number of times the image is viewed and in the end save this value, thus making it possible to establish an opening ranking.

For me it's easy to count the number of times the photo is viewed, the problem is to associate this value with the photo, for future use.
I thought about having an array like:

```
[[file_name00, ranking],[file_name01, ranking],[file_name02, ranking],[file_name03, ranking]...].
```

Each time an image is viewed the ranking would be increased and saved.
What I have difficulty doing is saving the array (on the server) so that the ranking value of each image does not disappear after the session ends.